# Api.ai intent hierarchy and duplicates

Tags: machine-learning, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Suppose we have the follow scenario

1. how much does debit card cost?
2. what is the expiration date? (refers to debit card)
3. how can I have a new one? (refers to debit card)
4. how much does credit card cost?
5. what is the expiration date? (refers to credit card)
6. how can I have a new one? (refers to credit card)

I've configured intents as below

- Debit card cost
- Debit card expiration date
- Debit card new
- Credit card cost
- Credit card expiration date
- Credit card new

In this way i'm able to reply to questions 1 and 4 but not 2, 3, 5 and 6.

I've, also, tried to use the context (https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-contexts), but i think it doesn't help us.

Can you show me, please, a solution to implement the above scenario?

Comment: What is the issue you had with contexts? This is exactly the kind of situation for which contexts are used.

Comment: Can you, please, give me an example on howto handle the above scenario? tnx

Comment: See my answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

*Aside: Your question should have provided a link to [your prior api.ai discussion](https://discuss.api.ai/t/intent-hieararchy-and-duplicates/4380/6) to provide more context. Also, your question, as stated, was misleading as you did not provide all relevant variant phrases for each of your intents. For example, you should have stated that intent #2 supported phrases like "what is the expiration date for the debit card" (without needing a prior invocation of intent #1). In future, please provide all relevant details.*

[Contexts](https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-contexts) *are* the correct way to handle this.

For example:

- Give the intent for #1 an output context of "debit".
- Give the intent for #4 an output context of "credit".
- Give the intents for #2 and #3 the input and output context of "debit".
- Give the intents for #5 and #6 an input and output context of "credit".

Comment: This is exactly that I wrote. With this solution your are unable to answer directly for question like "what is the expiration date of the bancomat?". Please see follow link https://discuss.api.ai/t/intent-hieararchy-and-duplicates/4380/6 Regards

Comment: See my updated answer. The last 2 bullets now also set the output context.

Comment: Sir I'm not interested in a polemic. I hope you can help me to solve my mission. Thank you

Comment: Not trying to be polemical. I was actually trying to help you get better at asking questions. We are all voluntarily answering questions for free, so help us to help you. Have you tried my updated answer?

Comment: Also, I needed to provide additional context in order for my updated answer to make more sense, since your question was missing that  context. Therefore, I added the "aside" to provide the context and to "gently" encourage you to be more complete when asking questions.